# .NET Core with Angular : How do I configure IIS for URL Rewriting in HTML5 mode?

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have built an angular 6 application with .Net core 2.1 and deployed to azure server on IIS web server. The routing is working fine on localhost when refresh, but not working on azure server. I checked angular [deployment guideline](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) and added following code in web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Now, I got into new problem. All the files now contains `index.html` content, instead of their respective file content.
[image]
[image]

What am I missing here? Do I need to make any changes to kestrel server

Comment: As I outlined in the answer, this rewrite is not necessary and doesn't work for ASP.NET Core. If your question is specific to ASP.NET Core's SPA Services / JavaScript Services, I suggest opening a question that includes your csproj and startup.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section of the angular guide does not apply to ASP.NET Core hosted Angular applications. Only for non-.NET or classic ASP.NET websites, a rewrite module definition is needed.

If you started your application based on ASP.NET Core's templates for angular or SPAs, you have rewriting / SPA fallback routes set up already.

I suggest starting from applications created with `dotnet new angular -o MyAngularApp` our using VS' angular templates (both use the same template packages).